# PHP : Compare two sentence

Tags: php, comparison

I need to compare below two sentences and the output should be percentage of matching

A: senior manager, production

B: senior manager, prodcution-sales

I tried by comparing each word of the sentence (code below). it works but i need much efficient way.

```
public function contact_title_match($old_title,$new_title)
{
   $new_title=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $new_title);
   $new_title_arr=explode(" ",$new_title);
   $count=count($new_title_arr);
   $index=0;
   if($count>0)
   {
      foreach($new_title_arr as $title_word)
      {
        if(stripos($old_title,$title_word)!==false)
            $index++;
      }
      if(($index/$count)>= 0.5) return 1;
      else                      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you at least show you've attempted this?

Comment: added the code which i tried

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a good job for [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php):

```
$sentence_a = "senior manager, production";
$sentence_b = "senior manager, prodcution-sales";
$percentage = 0;

similar_text( $sentence_a, $sentence_b, $percentage );

// The strings are 86 percent similar.
printf("The strings are %d percent similar.", $percentage);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/9Vx797uB

Comment: similar_text compares theoretically but my code compare logically. Here is the example: A="Database Administrator"  B="Database Admin"  similar_text_output : 77%  My_code_output: 100% .

Comment: @Muzaffer But "Admin" and "Administrator" aren't the same words. So on what basis would they be identical? Unless you're holding a database of synonyms as well. But then again, you could have some false-positives there where "Admin" could be found in the place of "Administer," but be confused as a synonym of "Administrator" or even "Administration".

Comment: idea here is to compare the title of a contact. i hope there wont be word "administration" in the title.